# Why do I have to use Google DNS on Home Router (CenturyLink)

Tags: router, dns

I have a CenturyLink DDR2200, working with my PrismTV (same a U-Verse, but it's IPTV).

For some reason, to use Apple's iMessage or FaceTime, I have to go into the device settings and change the DNS from `192.168.1.254` to `8.8.8.8`.

I know this isn't going to hurt anything, but why do I need to do it? It doesn't make since on why this should need to be done, because with my old Embarq stuff, it worked perfectly fine.

It's not only Apple's iMessage, its there Push Notification servers, and its my HP Printer Apps. I can't connect to the HP Printer App store and it doesn't work, but as soon as I go into Internet settings, and change it to `8.8.8.8`, it works!

Comment: on your network, what device is 192.168.1.254?

Comment: For Centurylink, that device is the router. And then currently, the router settings are Automatically Pick DNS servers.

Comment: In the router, It says "If 'Enable Automatic Assigned DNS' checkbox is selected, this residential gateway will accept the first received DNS assignment from one of the PPPoA, PPPoE or MER/DHCP enabled PVC(s) during the connection establishment."

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that the DNS server must be 8.8.8.8. I think it is more probable that the DNS server at 192.168.1.254 (the local one) is broken.

Try using other DNS providers to check (208.67.222.222, 156.154.70.1, 198.153.192.1)

Comment: Ok - I take it back, it doesn't have to be 8.8.8.8. Other public DNS providers work. The local one is broken, but shouldn't be. The local one is built into my router, and it supposedly pulls from something.

Comment: It says in the router, "If 'Enable Automatic Assigned DNS' checkbox is selected, this residential gateway will accept the first received DNS assignment from one of the PPPoA, PPPoE or MER/DHCP enabled PVC(s) during the connection establishment."

Comment: @David, I am not sure why the local one is broken, but that sounds like something that your ISP should deal with (it should be pointing to their DNS server)

Comment: I, personally, hate using ISP DNS servers. Verizon puts a splash screen up when you hit a url that doesn't exist.

Comment: @soandos They claim that its Apple and HP having internet connection issues. :/ The basic support people don't know crap.

Comment: @David, since we both know that makes no sense, either try escalating the call to someone that does know something, tell them it occurs on some other brand (ASUS, Dell, etc), or just use the workaround that just avoids their DNS. Nothing more I can say

Comment: @soandos Will try. I hate dumb support people. :\